# Can I log to an external file using a docker in spring java app?

Tags: java, spring, docker

I have spring app running inside a docker container and I use log4j for logging. Is it possible to write logs to external file? (I'm pretty new to docker)

In addition, I would not want to send logs to stdout (and then output to a file using the docker), is it possible to solve the problem in other ways? 
If it is not possible, how can I configure logging levels so that the docker can understand them and output?

Comment: For your first problem: Yes it is, you have to mount a volume which is shared between the host and guest. https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the logging file path in spring, you can add :

```
logging:
  file: /my/path/file.log
```

in your application.yaml

The logging file will be created inside your container. If you want your file to be accessible outside your container, create a volume in your docker image : https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

For exemple :

```
-v /my/real/path/:/my/container/path/
```

Docker doesn't know about logging level, but you can put environment variables in the application.yaml :

```
logging.level.root: ${LOGGING_LEVEL}
```

And then pass it to docker image with -e :

```
-e LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
```